# Change image on click of mouse by passing class name from one element to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I want to change the background image when I click the mouse. I want to remove the `class` from one `element` and add the same `class` to the next `element`. Then based on that particular `class` name, I want to perform `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` using `jquery`. However, only the first image is changed when I use the `class`. When I click the second image, it wont change. But when I replace the `class` with `div`, background image changes on each click until it reaches the last image. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing. Thank you.

```js
 $(function(){
     $("div").not(".active").hide();
     $(".active").click(function(){ //When I change .active to div, it works. 
      $(this).fadeOut(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).next().addClass("active");
       $(this).next().fadeIn()
      })
     })
    })
```

```css
  body, html{
      height: 100%;
      width:100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #one{
      background:url("../Images/one.jpg") fixed center no-repeat;
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #two{
      background:url("../Images/two.jpg");
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #three{
      background:url("../Images/three.jpg");
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
       <div  id="one" class="active"></div>
       <div  id="two"></div>
       <div  id="three"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `on()` instead of `click()` because you are adding the class dynamically.

```
$(function(){
    $("div").not(".active").hide();
    $("body").on('click', '.active', function(){ //When I change .active to div, it works. 
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
                $(this).next().addClass("active");
            $(this).next().fadeIn()
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `.delegate`
change your code like this:

```
   $('body').delegate('.active', 'click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).next().addClass("active");
            $(this).next().fadeIn()
        })
    })
```

or you change bind the `click` on `body` to judge the `e.target`

see the details here [delegate](http://devdocs.io/jquery/delegate)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

- first add specific class `.bg-div` to these divs because targeting *ALL* divs with this `$("div")` is so generic and it'll hide everything other than the active one, in case you have other divs they'll be hidden.
- hide all divs with class `.bg-div` except the one which has `.active`.
- on click event, you can still target `bg-div` div because there's only one which has `.active` class, since all other `bgDivs` are hidden already from the previous step. `fadeOut()` this one.
- increase the counter `index` by one.
- now if the value of `index` equals the length -number - of `bgDivs`, then reset the coutner to **`0`**, this is for when you're showing the last `bg-div`.
- `fadeIn()` the next div.

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/6pprfb8d/)

```js
$(function() {
  var bgDivs = $(".bg-div"),
    index = 0;

  bgDivs.not(".active").hide();
  bgDivs.on('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    index += 1;
    // if the counter value is less than the number of bgDivs, keep this value
    // else, set it to 0 and start over because we're on the last div
    index = (index < bgDivs.length) ? index : 0;
    $(bgDivs[index]).fadeIn('fast');
  });
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bg-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#one {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/1000x700?text=one") fixed center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#two {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/1000x700?text=two") fixed center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#three {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/1000x700?text=three") fixed center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="one" class="bg-div active"></div>
  <div id="two" class="bg-div"></div>
  <div id="three" class="bg-div"></div>
</body>
```

---

**Update 1:**

You'd notice there's a moment where the horizontal scrollbar appears when while switching the background div, this is because these divs are stacked under each others but when hidden there's no problem, the problem only appears the moment you switch the background div, to fix this add these lines to your `.bg-div` CSS:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/6pprfb8d/1/)

---

**Update 2:**

You can totally get rid of `.active` class and don't rely on it if you add generic `display:none;` to your `.bg-div` CSS, then in the `#one` rule add `display:block`. by doing this you no more need this line:

```
bgDivs.not(".active").hide();
```

[**jsFiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/6pprfb8d/2/)

This is useful not only because of less code, but also the background divs other than the first one will be hidden when the page first load from the beginning since it's in the CSS and not wait until your js script to hide them